# Different conditions When Sum in same query

Tags: sql

I have 6 querys that do the same but have differents conditions in WHERE statements. Is it possible to get all the criterias for each query  and get 6 differents results? I think that I can use UNION ALL but the queries are so big. Below are the queries:

**query 1**(Dv1)

```
SELECT
  *Dv1* AS Scaled,
   SUM(h.weight_x1000000/1000000) AS Total,
   SUM(CASE when h.windows >0 then h.weight_x1000000/1000000 end) AS Ra,
   SUM(case when h.doors > 0 then h.weight_x1000000/1000000 end) AS Re

FROM store h INNER JOIN 
     sales p ON
     p.id = h.id 

WHERE h.date Between 2018 AND 2020
    AND p.status = 'O';
```

**query 2**(Dv2)

```
SELECT
   *Dv2* AS Scaled,
   SUM(h.weight_x1000000/1000000) AS Total,
   SUM(CASE when h.windows >0 then h.weight_x1000000/1000000 end) AS Ra,
   SUM(case when h.doors > 0 then h.weight_x1000000/1000000 end) AS Re

FROM store h INNER JOIN 
     sales p ON
     p.id = h.id 

WHERE h.date Between 2018 AND 2020
   AND p.status = 'O'
   AND h.location = 'AM';
```

**query 3**(Dv3)

```
SELECT
   *Dv3* AS Scaled,
   SUM(h.weight_x1000000/1000000) AS Total,
   SUM(CASE when h.windows >0 then h.weight_x1000000/1000000 end) AS Ra,
   SUM(case when h.doors > 0 then h.weight_x1000000/1000000 end) AS Re

FROM store h INNER JOIN 
   sales p ON
   p.id = h.id 

WHERE h.date Between 2018 AND 2020
   AND p.status = 'O'
   AND h.location = 'AM'
   AND h.reg > 2;
```

.
.
.
**query 6**(Dv6)

```
SELECT
   *Dv6* AS Scaled,
   SUM(h.weight_x1000000/1000000) AS Total,
   SUM(CASE when h.windows >0 then h.weight_x1000000/1000000 end) AS Ra,
   SUM(case when h.doors > 0 then h.weight_x1000000/1000000 end) AS Re

FROM store h INNER JOIN 
   sales p ON
   p.id = h.id 

WHERE h.date Between 2018 AND 2020
   AND p.status = 'O'
   AND h.location = 'AM'
   AND h.reg > 2
   AND h.rec = 'R'
   AND h.ver= 'EM'
   AND p.regx > 2;
```

**Output expected:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Create Table #Cond (Scaled Varchar(Max), Conditn varchar(max))

Insert Into #Cond (Scaled, Conditn)
Select 'Dv1', '' Union
Select 'Dv2', ' AND h.location = ''AM'' ' Union 
Select 'Dv3', ' AND h.reg > 2 '  Union 
Select 'Dv4', ' AND h.rec = ''R'' ' Union 
Select 'Dv5', ' AND h.status = ''EM'' ' Union 
Select 'Dv6', ' AND p.regx > 2 '



Declare @QryTmpl varchar(Max) =
'SELECT
   ''@Scaled'' AS Scaled,
   SUM(h.weight_x1000000/1000000) AS Total,
   SUM(CASE when h.windows >0 then h.weight_x1000000/1000000 end) AS Ra,
   SUM(case when h.doors > 0 then h.weight_x1000000/1000000 end) AS Re
FROM store h INNER JOIN 
   sales p ON
   p.id = h.id 
WHERE h.date Between 2018 AND 2020 AND p.status = ''O''
   @COND '  


DECLARE  @NL varchar(1) = char(13), @SQL varchar(max) = '', @MultCond varchar(Max) = ''

Select @MultCond = @MultCond + Conditn + @NL, 
    @SQL = @SQL + Replace(Replace(@QryTmpl,'@Scaled', Scaled),'@COND', @MultCond) + ' Union All ' + @NL
from #Cond order by Scaled

Select @SQL = @SQL + '~'
Select @SQL = Replace(@SQL,' Union All ' + @NL + '~','')

-- For Testing (View the Results as Text)
Select @SQL

Exec(@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like following, I have put your `Query 1` and `Query 2` together for an example. Get your `where` condition filter which are not common inside `sum()`.

```
SELECT
  Dv AS Scaled,
  SUM(h.weight_x1000000/1000000) AS Total,
  SUM(CASE when h.windows > 0 then h.weight_x1000000/1000000 end) AS Ra1,
  SUM(case when and h.doors > 0 then h.weight_x1000000/1000000 end) AS Re1,
  SUM(CASE when (h.location = 'AM' and h.windows > 0) then h.weight_x1000000/1000000 end) AS Ra2,
  SUM(case when (h.location = 'AM' and h.doors > 0) then h.weight_x1000000/1000000 end) AS Re2


FROM store h INNER JOIN 
     sales p ON
     p.id = h.id 

WHERE h.date Between 2018 AND 2020
and p.status = 'O'
```

Your second option is `union all`.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid "union all" 'cause the queries are so big. With your answer I get a lot of results and I'm trying to get just 6 raws and not just one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about the following

```
Select 
   sum(hWtDivByMil) as total_1,
   sum(WindCond * hWtDivByMil) as ra_1,
   sum(DoorCond * hWtDivByMil) as re_1,

   sum(LocnCond * hWtDivByMil) as total_2,
   sum(WindCond * LocnCond * hWtDivByMil) as ra_2,
   sum(DoorCond * LocnCond * hWtDivByMil) as re_2,

   sum(RegCond * LocnCond * hWtDivByMil) as total_3,
   sum(RegCond * LocnCond * WindCond * hWtDivByMil) as ra_3,
   sum(RegCond * LocnCond * DoorCond * hWtDivByMil) as re_3,

   sum(RecCond * RegCond * LocnCond * hWtDivByMil) as total_4,
   sum(RecCond * RegCond * LocnCond * WindCond * hWtDivByMil) as ra_4,
   sum(RecCond * RegCond * LocnCond * DoorCond * hWtDivByMil) as re_4,

   sum(VerCond * RecCond * RegCond * LocnCond * hWtDivByMil) as total_5,
   sum(VerCond * RecCond * RegCond * LocnCond * WindCond * hWtDivByMil) as ra_5,
   sum(VerCond * RecCond * RegCond * LocnCond * DoorCond * hWtDivByMil) as re_5,

   sum(RegXCond * VerCond * RecCond * RegCond * LocnCond * hWtDivByMil) as total_6,
   sum(RegXCond * VerCond * RecCond * RegCond * LocnCond * WindCond * hWtDivByMil) as ra_6,
   sum(RegXCond * VerCond * RecCond * RegCond * LocnCond * DoorCond * hWtDivByMil) as re_6,
from
(
select h.date, h.location, h.reg, h.rec, h.ver, p.status, p.regx, 
    h.weight_x1000000/1000000 as hWtDivByMil,
    Case when h.windows     > 0     then 1 Else 0 End as WindCond,
    Case when h.doors       > 0     then 1 Else 0 End as DoorCond,
    Case when h.location    = 'AM'  then 1 Else 0 End as LocnCond,
    Case when h.reg         > 2     then 1 Else 0 End as RegCond,
    Case when h.rec         = 'R'   then 1 Else 0 End as RecCond,
    Case when h.ver         = 'EM   then 1 Else 0 End as VerCond,
    Case when h.regx        > 2     then 1 Else 0 End as RegXCond
from store h 
inner join sales p 
    on p.id = h.id 
where h.date between 2018 and 2020 
    and p.status = 'O'
)Q
```

Comment: The query has to return one colum for the "Total", "Ra" and "Re" and 6 raws(for each query), but thanks

Comment: Jozamvg , are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: Yes, I could use UNION ALL but I the query is too large and I want to figure out another way to do it

Comment: check my new solution (earlier I thought you need all columns)